# Can I safely distribute a hashed password?

Tags: security, sha

I have an application whose source code is checked into a public repository. This source code includes configuration files, and in those configuration files are SHA-256 hashed passwords.

My understanding is that when it comes to hashed passwords, an end user doesn't actually have to enter the password you used to generate the hash, but *any* password that generates the same hash value. I believe this is called a collision.

So can I display my hashed passwords in public with a reasonable assurance that someone can't take that hash and then generate a password (or generate a collection) that can be used to get access to my application? Is that a guarantee that these hashing algorithms try to make?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687518/how-long-can-a-hash-left-out-in-the-open-be-considered-safe looks like it pretty much answers the question. It would seem that as long as you use a password that is not likely to be found in a rainbow table, you should be pretty safe.

Comment: As long as you properly salt your passwords, leave them sitting out in the open as long as you want. But no hashing method in the universe will protect your password if it's just a direct `sha2('letmein')`. Common/simple passwords will fall instantly to any basic password checker.

Comment: Belongs on Security.StackExchange.Com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no known practical attacks against SHA-2 in the general case. It's generally considered better to keep hashed passwords secret, though, because there *are* rainbow tables, dictionary attacks, and other such things. If you took the proper precautions such as salting, round robin hashing, and having a nice long passphrase, it *should* be perfectly safe.

It's still better to not do this, though. You never know what cryptographic attacks might be developed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is not likely for someone to reverse a HASH, SHA1, SALT etc. There are some ways out there to reverse one, but if you think your at that much of a risk I'd use SHA1 and SALT for maximum security. Having a long password makes it difficult to reverse, but unless they are real seasoned coders, your not very like to be a victim of it.

Read up on the algorithms at Wikipedia...

SHA1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

SALT: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Just use a unique password and you should be fine ;-)